# if there's a other way to make the process of image processing became faster using python?

Tags: vb.net, python-2.7

I developed a system that can detect the disease using image processing, but when i finished it. It takes too long to give an output, 40-50 mins. Im using python as the system process and VB for GUI. My library of Image Processing is SimpleCV. I would like to ask if there's a other way to make the process of image processing became faster, or it just a typical slow process ?
Thank you :D

Comment: Put your snippet code too.

Comment: You need to measure how long each stage takes so that you can decide where changes could usefully be made. For example, you *might* find that it is reading the files that takes longest. Also, if the computer has insufficient RAM then it will have to use a swap file on the disk, which will slow it down a lot.